# Таксономия для произвольного типа записи

Tags: wordpress

Создал произвольный тип записей, подскажите как привязать к этим типам записей таксономию "метки", как в стандартном типе записей "post".
В документации по этому поводу пишут:

> **taxonomies**(массив)
>       Массив зарегистрированных таксономий, которые будут связанны с этим типом записей, например: **category** или **post_tag**. Может быть
>   использовано вместо вызова функции
>   `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`. Таксономии нужно регистрировать с
>   помощью функции `register_taxonomy()`.

Добавлял параметр taxonomies со значением array(0 => 'post_tag'), но эффекта не дало,
Или все же придется регистрировать новую таксономию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно привязать к кастомному типу поста существующий тип таксономии, то достаточно указать ее при создании типа в параметре `taxonomies`:

```
register_post_type( 'my_type',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'          => 'my_type',
        'singular_name' => 'My type',
        'new_item' => 'New my type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new my type',
        'add_new' => 'Add my type',
      ),
      'public'      => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'my_type' ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
      'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'), // массив поддерживаемых таксономий
    )
  );
```

Comment: Да спасибо, я все верно делал, только таксономию добавлял для другого типа записей.... И мучился что нет ее для нужной...... Невнимательность......